# Ubuntu alt + shift in Eclipse change language and cannot use any other shortcut

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse, ubuntu-17.04

When pressing alt+shift in Eclipse it changes the layout as (alt+shift) is the shortcut to change the language, any other shortcut start with alt+shift cannot be used.
Is there anyway to solve this conflict so I can use alt+shift for change language and use another Eclipse shortcuts like "alt+shift+s" ...

Comment: You can change the settings for switching between layouts. [Refer to this possible solution](https://askubuntu.com/a/967493)